# Spring Boot - Throwing IOException when mocking BufferedReader

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am currently trying to test a service in Spring Boot. It should read a file from a BufferedReader. The first test works just fine, but the one where I try to mock the IOException is not.

HTMLService:

```
@MockBean
HTMLService htmlService;

public String read(String fileName, String username) {
    
    String s = null;
    String filePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
    String path = filePath+"/src/main/resources/html/"+fileName;
    
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {

        String line = br.readLine();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
            line = br.readLine();
        }

        s = sb.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    s = s.replace("KINO-USERNAME", username);
    
    return s;
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
void testReadException() {
    when(htmlService.read("Registration.html", "DrBackmischung")).thenReturn("Test");
    try {
        BufferedReader br = Mockito.mock(BufferedReader.class);
        when(br.readLine()).thenThrow(IOException.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    assertThrows(IOException.class, new Executable() {

        @Override
        public void execute() throws Throwable {
            htmlService.read("Registration.html", "DrBackmischung");
            
        }
        
    });
}
```

I've tried mocking it different ways, but nothing seems to work. Is there a working approach?

Comment: you can't mock what is created inline with new. One option would be to refactor logic from reader construction, then you'd be able to test it using simple StringReader

Comment: `String path = filePath+"/src/main/resources/html/"+fileName;` is bad and will fail when you pack and run jar. The spring way would be through Resource; either using ClassPathResource directly, or adding @Value atop of Resource with value `classpath:...`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mocking `BufferedReader`, however the `BufferedReader` used inside your `HTMLService` class is `new BufferedReader`, so it is initializing a new instance of BufferedReader, and definitley not pointing towards your mock instance..

Why dont you just mock the return of the `read` method() to throw IOException instead.

```
when(htmlService.read("Registration.html", "DrBackmischung")).thenThrow(IOException.class);
```

Honesty I cant see the validity of such a test (Towards that a BufferedReader throws an IOException)..unless you have an important business logic (Another method/Service, that could be impacted), but testing an isolated IOException doesnt seem to provide any benefit.